# Permission denied in mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I'm trying to write a command on mac terminal using the root, but it shows me that the permission denied, when I use the sudo it shows that the command not found

can any one please help me

```
aftheers-MacBook-Air:scripts root# ./ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade.sh
-sh: ./ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: Did you make the file executable using `chmod +x ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade.sh`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to make the file executable:

```
chmod +x ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid permission denied prompt, type this command and continue

```
sudo su
```

> Install the packages in this admin mode,

then go back to normal mode

```
exit
```

Comment: explanation would be good